# Remove Double Quotes From Formula Results - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am having an issue when building a CSV report in Crystal Reports (using the Visual Studio plug in)

I have three columns of data (UserID, Name, Location), I have used a formula to create a comma separated entry for each row of date:

CSTR({Command.USERID},0,'') + ',' + {Command.NAME} + ',' + {Command.LOCATION}

However the output is:

“0009,John Smith,London”

“0008,Johann Schmidt,R101”

Each row is starts and finishes with double quotes.

How do I remove/prevent double quotes from appear around formula results?

The desired result is:

0009,John Smith,London

0008,Johann Schmidt,R101

Thanks

Comment: is problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `REPLACE` function would do the trick. Try this:

```
Replace(CSTR({Command.USERID},0,'') + ',' + {Command.NAME} + ',' + {Command.LOCATION},""""," " )
```

Note:The extra double quote, i.e. a quadruple double quote.This is known as **escaping** a character. The extra double quote escapes the action normally triggered by the second double quote.

OR

```
Replace(CSTR({Command.USERID},0,'') + ',' + {Command.NAME} + ',' + {Command.LOCATION},chrW(34)," " )
```

chrW(34) is equivalent to double quotes.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it looks like there is a something in Crystal which is encasing the Formula results in quotes after the formula has be ran.

Comment: Another thing that you can try is use the `REPLACE` function in `Display String` property of the formula field.

Comment: `REPLACE(CURRENTFIELDVALUE,""""," ")`